# How to load bootstrap modal with error after page reload (using codeigniter)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I have a popup model where user add the course name. I have added a form validation in my codeigniter controller and then if the validation is false, I am loading my view again with a form error showing above form input in the model, but due to page reload the model closes. What I want is if the form validation is false I want to reload the page with the modal open. I am not familiar with ajax. Any help will be really appreciated.

Codeigniter Controller

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('course_name', 'Course Name', 'required|max_length[30]');
$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="text-danger">', '</div>');
if ($this->form_validation->run() ) {
  echo "inserted";
}else {
  $this->load->view('admin/coursename');
}
```

Codeigniter View (Modal Code)

```
<center><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add Course</button><center>
    <!-- Modal -->

    <div class="modal fade"  data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" id="myModal" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Add Course</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
              <form action="" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="name">Course Name:</label>
                        <?php echo form_error('course_name'); ?>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="course_name" placeholder="Enter course name...">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                      <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
              </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you familiar with jqury. Then i have solution.

Comment: you have added ajax tag so are you submitting the form using ajax?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery ".ajax()" method to call the validation controller without refreshing, then the controller echoes its result which your j-query code will now have to interprete. An example code below.
You can modify your view code like this:

```
<div class="modal fade"  data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Add Course</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="err">

            </div>
            <form action="" method="post" id ="yourform">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Course Name:</label>
                    <?php echo form_error('course_name'); ?>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="course_name" placeholder="Enter course name...">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
$("#yourform").submit(function (event) {
    var form = $(this).closest('form');
    field1 = $(form).find('.field1').val();
    field2 = $(form).find('.field2').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo site_url('your/controller/url') ?>',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {field2: field2, field2: field2},

        success: function (result) {
            //alert(result);return false;
            if (result == 1)
            {
                location.reload();
            } else
            {
                $('#err').html(result);
            }

        }
    });

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Then you can configure your controller like such :

```
<?php

$this->form_validation->set_rules('course_name', 'Course Name',    'required|max_length[30]');
$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="text-danger">',    '</div>');
if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
echo "1";
} else {
echo "<b>" . validation_errors() . "</b>";
}
?>
```

Hope i helped

Answer (score 0):

you can use location.reload("Your Page Name") function in ajax success function.